# What does ことだけ mean in general?

Tags: translation, particle-だけ

According to [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17849/what-is-koto-used-for?noredirect=1&lq=1), "noun + の + こと" mostly means "regarding noun" when it is used.

By adding a だけ to the end, (so that it's now "noun + の + こと + だけ") does this change the meaning to something else, or does it change the amount of regard given to the noun?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> does this change the meaning to something else, or does it change the amount of regard given to the noun?

Neither. It **adds** the meaning of "only". When X is a noun, Xのこと forms another noun phrase. And `noun + だけ` just means "only ～". So:

- Xのこと = things regarding X; things about X
- Xのことだけ = only things regarding X; only things about X

> - あなたのことを考えています。
>     I am thinking about you.
> - あなたのことだけを考えています。
>     I am thinking only about you.
>     (*Not*: I am thinking things that are related only to you)