# What is the difference between ある日 and ある日のこと?

Tags: word-choice, nuances

For example:

> ある日のこと、たろうは、また海へ出て。

As I understand ある日 means "one day". What does the のこと do to it?

Possibly related? [What is the こと in sentences such as あなたのことが好きだ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2102/what-is-the-%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8-in-sentences-such-as-%E3%81%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AE%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8C%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A0) and [What is “koto” used for?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17849/what-is-koto-used-for?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Related...duplicate? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32215/7810